# Running migrations: No migrations to apply

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to test `django-embed-video` from their official git reposiotry [Django-embed-video example project](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video/tree/v1.2.0).

Here are their [instructions](https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/example-project.html):

> Example project For easy start with using django-embed-video, you can
>   take a look at example project. It is located in example_project
>   directory in root of repository.
>
> Running example project Install requirements:
>
> ```
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> Create database:
>
> ```
> python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb --noinput
> ```
>
> Or, for older versions of Django:
>
> ```
> python manage.py syncdb --noinput
> ```
>
> Run testing server:
>
> ```
> python manage.py runserver
> ```
>
> Take a look at `http://localhost:8000` . You can log in to
>   administration with username admin and password admin.

I followed all their instructions when I run.

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb --noinput
```

I get the following

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: embed_video, example_project, messages, posts
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

When I run

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

I get the following

Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 13, 2019 - 15:52:08
Django version 1.11.20, using settings 'example_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` I see the following

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you added it to your installed apps in settings?

Comment: I just cloned their app from git nothing else I have so far, I just wanna test and see how it works

Comment: Can you check the database to see if the fixtures (the initial sample data) were loaded?

Comment: try running `manage.py loaddata initial_data.yaml`

Comment: Did you install PyYAML? (should have if you did `pip install ...`)